# How can I define a function that can accumulate its parameter?

Tags: function-construction

For example, write a function `add`:

add[3]  return 3

add[4]  return 7

add[10] return 17

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### `Module` and `Function`

Possibly the easiest way is to use a unique symbol generated with `Module` to hold the value:

```
Module[{x = 0},
 add = x += # &;
]

add[3]
add[4]
add[10]
```

> ```
> 3
> 7
> 17
> ```

Or generating such a function:

```
makeAccumulator[init_: 0] := 
  Module[{x = init},
    x += # &
  ]

add = makeAccumulator[99];

add[3]
add[4]
add[10]
```

> ```
> 102
> 106
> 116
> ```

The simplest way I can think of to reset this counter to e.g. 77:

```
add[77 - add[0]];

add[3]
```

> ```
> 80
> ```

---

### `DownValues` definitions

Another approach is to store the value in a separate rule attached to the same symbol:

```
add[] = 0;
add[x_] := add[] += x;

add[3]
add[4]
add[10]
```

> ```
> 3
> 7
> 17
> ```

Here I used `add[]` to hold the value but you could use any other pattern you wish.

It easy to reset the counter: just do `add[] = (* new value *)`

Comment: @yohbs By the way, perfect!: http://i.stack.imgur.com/j8vPn.png

Comment: yes! unfortunately, I've earned some reputation now, and I can no longer take over the world.

Comment: Why not Unique instead of Module to generate the counter storage? While it works, I'm not sure it's a good idea to rely on leaking Module variables this way. But I bring it up because I'd be glad to understand why it might be relied on.

Comment: @JoelKlein I believe you could use `Unique["x", Temporary]` to get similar behavior to the `Module` but you will still need `With` to get it into the parts of the code you want so you're "reinventing the wheel" as I see it.  I don't see this as "leaking" variables but simply using `Module` efficiently.  Admittedly I'm not the best at exhaustive analysis of programming constructs; if you're interested you should ask Leonid.