# I need help converting a list into a list of rules for LayeredGraphPlot

Tags: graphs-and-networks, expression-manipulation

```
rules={{"A2", "BO"}, {"A2", "BO"}, {"A2", "BO"}, {"A2", "BO"}, {"A2", 
"BO"}, {"A2", "BO"}, {"A2", "BO"}, {"A2", "BO"}, {"A2", 
"BO"}, {"A2", "BO"}, {"A2", "BO"}, {"A2", "BO"}, {"A2", 
"BO"}, {"A2", "BO"}, {"A2", "BO"}, {"A2", "BO"}, {"A2", 
"BO"}, {"A2", "BX"}, {"A2", "BO"}, {"A2", "BO"}, {"A2", 
"BX"}, {"A2", "BE"}, {"A2", "BO"}, {"A2", "BO"}, {"A2", 
"BO"}, {"A2", "BO"}, {"A2", "BX"}, {"A2", "BX"}, {"A2", 
"BE"}, {"A2", "BO"}, {"A2", "BO"}, {"A2", "BO"}, {"A2", 
"BX"}, {"A2", "BO"}, {"A2", "BO"}, {"A2", "BX"}, {"A2", 
"BO"}, {"A1", "BL"}, {"A1", "BL"}, {"A1", "BL"}, {"A1", 
"BL"}, {"A1", "BL"}, {"A1", "BL"}, {"A1", "BP"}, {"A1", 
"BP"}, {"A1", "BL"}, {"A1", "BP"}, {"A1", "BL"}, {"A1", 
"BP"}, {"A1", "BP"}, {"A1", "BP"}, {"A1", "BP"}, {"A1", 
"BP"}, {"A1", "BL"}, {"A1", "BP"}, {"A1", "BL"}, {"A1", 
"BL"}, {"A1", "BL"}, {"A1", "BP"}, {"A1", "BL"}, {"A1", 
"BP"}, {"A1", "BP"}, {"A1", "BL"}, {"A1", "BE"}, {"A1", 
"BL"}, {"A1", "BL"}, {"A1", "BP"}, {"A1", "BL"}, {"A1", 
"BE"}, {"F2", "BO"}, {"F2", "BL"}, {"F2", "BP"}, {"F1", 
"BL"}, {"F1", "BP"}, {"F1", "BL"}, {"F1", "BP"}, {"F2", 
"BL"}, {"F2", "BL"}, {"F2", "BO"}, {"F2", "BO"}, {"F2", 
"BO"}, {"F2", "BO"}, {"F1", "BL"}, {"F1", "BL"}, {"F1", 
"BL"}, {"F1", "BL"}, {"F1", "BP"}, {"F1", "BP"}, {"F1", 
"BL"}, {"F1", "BL"}, {"F1", "BL"}, {"F1", "BO"}};
```

I have a list that represented as follows.
A1,A2,F1 are the locations of compartments, BO,BE,BL... are the descriptions of the items within A1,A2,A3.

I would like to visualize the placement of the items within each compartment to test for the lack of sortation. I was thinking of a LayeredGraphPlot but my list needs work. How would I make a function to convert my list to look like this.

```
{"A2" -> "BO1", "A2" -> "BO2", "A2" -> "BO3", "A2" -> "BO4",
```

"A2" -> "BO5".....}
The order can not be changes and each item numbered (i.e. BO1,BO2...BOn),the numbering of each item is the total of the individual item.

Thanks Bob

Comment: try using Apply, for instance Apply[Rule, rules, {1}]

Comment: Bob, I see that you have been on-line recently but you did not comment on my answer.  Is the output as you desire?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I think the answer is perfect! I should've thought of that. And I'm trying to get used to the app for this forum. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome, and I am glad I could help.  I did not mean to rush you to Accept my answer.  (Personally I wait 24 hours before accepting an answer to give everyone a chance to answer first.)  I just wondered if I had misunderstood.  I imagine you'll find more uses for that simple `count` method; I know I do.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard One look at your answer, and I knew it was the correct one, thanks again. And I'm still trying to get used to this new app I got today.One more question, would this be a neat and tidy way to visualize my so-called sortation? Or is there an alternative that might be better.

Comment: I must admit that I do not understand what you wish to visualize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want this:

```
Module[{count},
 count[__] = 0;
 # -> #2 <> ToString[++count[##]] & @@@ rules
]
```

> ```
> {"A2" -> "BO1", "A2" -> "BO2", "A2" -> "BO3", "A2" -> "BO4", "A2" -> "BO5", "A2" -> "BO6",
>   "A2" -> "BO7", "A2" -> "BO8", "A2" -> "BO9", "A2" -> "BO10", "A2" -> "BO11", 
>  "A2" -> "BO12", "A2" -> "BO13", "A2" -> "BO14", "A2" -> "BO15", "A2" -> "BO16", 
>  "A2" -> "BO17", "A2" -> "BX1", "A2" -> "BO18", "A2" -> "BO19", "A2" -> "BX2", 
>  "A2" -> "BE1", "A2" -> "BO20", "A2" -> "BO21", "A2" -> "BO22", "A2" -> "BO23", 
>  "A2" -> "BX3", "A2" -> "BX4", "A2" -> "BE2", "A2" -> "BO24", "A2" -> "BO25", 
>  "A2" -> "BO26", "A2" -> "BX5", "A2" -> "BO27", "A2" -> "BO28", "A2" -> "BX6", 
>  "A2" -> "BO29", "A1" -> "BL1", "A1" -> "BL2", "A1" -> "BL3", "A1" -> "BL4", 
>  "A1" -> "BL5", "A1" -> "BL6", "A1" -> "BP1", "A1" -> "BP2", "A1" -> "BL7", "A1" -> "BP3",
>   "A1" -> "BL8", "A1" -> "BP4", "A1" -> "BP5", "A1" -> "BP6", "A1" -> "BP7", 
>  "A1" -> "BP8", "A1" -> "BL9", "A1" -> "BP9", "A1" -> "BL10", "A1" -> "BL11", 
>  "A1" -> "BL12", "A1" -> "BP10", "A1" -> "BL13", "A1" -> "BP11", "A1" -> "BP12", 
>  "A1" -> "BL14", "A1" -> "BE1", "A1" -> "BL15", "A1" -> "BL16", "A1" -> "BP13", 
>  "A1" -> "BL17", "A1" -> "BE2", "F2" -> "BO1", "F2" -> "BL1", "F2" -> "BP1", 
>  "F1" -> "BL1", "F1" -> "BP1", "F1" -> "BL2", "F1" -> "BP2", "F2" -> "BL2", "F2" -> "BL3",
>   "F2" -> "BO2", "F2" -> "BO3", "F2" -> "BO4", "F2" -> "BO5", "F1" -> "BL3", 
>  "F1" -> "BL4", "F1" -> "BL5", "F1" -> "BL6", "F1" -> "BP3", "F1" -> "BP4", "F1" -> "BL7",
>   "F1" -> "BL8", "F1" -> "BL9", "F1" -> "BO1"}
> ```

---

Recommended reading:

- [How can I define a function that can accumulate its parameter?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18799/121)
- [Replace with position and order number](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/27173/121)
- [Accumulate second elements in sublist](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/46830/121)