# Count the times a digit has appeared in a list as I scan the list

Tags: list-manipulation

Suppose I have a list `l`:

```
SeedRandom[1]
l = RandomInteger[5, 10]
```

> `{4, 2, 4, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0}`

I want to count the times a certain digit has appeared in the list as I scan the list from left to right. I'd like the output to have the for $\color{red}{\text{\{digit, counts\}}}$ for every element.

This is my current method:

```
FoldPairList[{{#2, Count[#1, #2] + 1}, Append[#1, #2]}&, {}, l]
```

> `{{4, 1}, {2, 1}, {4, 2}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}, {0, 2}, {0, 3}, {2, 2}, {0, 4}, {0, 5}}`

Any other elegant and mainstream method that can do this?

Comment: Related: [(18799)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18799/121), [(27173)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/27173/121), [(40377)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40377/121), [(46830)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/46830/121)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is a semi-imperative method:

```
runningCount[list_] := Module[{c}, c[_] = 0; {#, ++c[#]} & /@ list]
```

Example:

```
runningCount[{4, 2, 4, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0}]

(* {{4, 1}, {2, 1}, {4, 2}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}, {0, 2}, {0, 3}, {2, 2}, {0, 4}, {0, 5}} *)
```

Comment: congratulations, you are now number 2 in the speed ranking.

Comment: This is my go-to method, but surely `++c[#]` is cleaner?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes... changed.

Answer (score 14):

```
cnts = Transpose[{#, Module[{o = Ordering@#}, 
                      o[[o]] = Join @@ Range@Tally[#[[o]]][[All, 2]]; o]}] &;
```

Use (*l* containing desired list target):

```
result=cnts@l;
```

Will be order(s) of magnitude faster on large lists than OP method.

Comment: I realize the `Count` is a very low efficiency function,which cost almost 70% of time.

Answer (score 11):

I'll join the party :)

```
Clear["Global`*"]
lst = {4, 2, 4, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0}; 
Scan[(x[#] = 0) &, Union[lst]]; 
(Last@Reap@Scan[ Sow[{#, ++x[#]} ] &, lst])[[1]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The idea is to set up a hash lookup counter of each number in the list, initially at zero. Then scan the list, incrementing the counter by one using lookup each time.

### Timings

I did basic timings for the solutions given. all are using this list, and using `AbsoluteTiming` command

```
 lst = RandomInteger[10000, 50000];
```

**Result**

```
Ciao solution: 0.015831 seconds  
W Reach solution: 0.15155 seconds
Nasser solution: 0.22417 seconds
David Keith solution: 2.3196  seconds
A.G. solution:  145.95 seconds
```

**Code**

```
Clear["Global`*"]
SeedRandom[1]
lst = RandomInteger[10000, 50000];
AbsoluteTiming[
 Scan[(x[#] = 0) &, Union[lst]];
 (Last@Reap@Scan[Sow[{#, ++x[#]}] &, lst])[[1]];
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Clear["Global`*"]
SeedRandom[1]
lst = RandomInteger[10000, 50000];
AbsoluteTiming[
 Table[First@Tally@Reverse@Take[lst, i], {i, 1, Length@lst}];]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Clear["Global`*"]
SeedRandom[1]
lst = RandomInteger[10000, 50000];
counts[l_] := 
 Table[{l[[n]], Count[l[[1 ;; n]], l[[n]]]}, {n, Length[l]}]
AbsoluteTiming[counts[lst];]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Clear["Global`*"]
SeedRandom[1]
lst = RandomInteger[10000, 50000];
cnts = Transpose[{#, 
     Module[{o = Ordering@#}, 
      o[[o]] = Join @@ Range@Tally[#[[o]]][[All, 2]]; o]}] &;
AbsoluteTiming[cnts@lst;]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Clear["Global`*"]
SeedRandom[1]
lst = RandomInteger[10000, 50000];
runningCount[list_] := Module[{c}, c[_] = 0; {#, c[#] += 1} & /@ list]
AbsoluteTiming[runningCount[lst];]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks for taking time to... time!

Answer (score 7):

Elegant :^)

```
Table[First@Tally@Reverse@Take[l, i], {i, 1, Length@l}]
{{4, 1}, {2, 1}, {4, 2}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}, {0, 2}, {0, 3}, {2, 2}, {0, 4}, {0, 5}}
```

(note that `Tally` lists distinct elements in the order they appear in `l`, thus the `Reverse`).

This is not however an *efficient* way to proceed for long lists, say $n\geq1000$. Time-complexity appears to be $O(n^2)$ while clearly a linear-time solution is feasible. Here are the running times for lists of size $n$ (random integers are in the $0-500$ range).

[image: Mathematica graphics]

*Times are on a 2015 Macbook Pro*.

Comment: Nice work....+)

Comment: Mobile right now, so can't test, but eyeballing it seems like it will be dreadfully slow on large lists. Did you test it on any?

Comment: @Ciao Yes, at first sight it would seem to be $O(n^2)$. Timing was .2 sec on a 10,000 list and 21 sec on a 100,000 list.

Answer (score 7):

Compiling is usually the best approach for problems like this where an iteration depends on previous state. Here is a compiled function to get the counts (basically a compiled version of the approaches of @Nasser and @WReach)

```
iCount = Compile[{{d,_Integer,1}},
    Module[{z = ConstantArray[0, Max[d]-Min[d]+1]},
        Table[ ++z[[i]], {i, d-Min[d]+1}]
    ],
    CompilationTarget->"C"
];
```

`iCount` only produces the counts. Creating the actual desired output inside the compiled function was actually slower than using uncompiled code. So, here is the final function:

```
runningCount = Transpose @ Developer`ToPackedArray[{#, iCount[#]}]&;
```

Example (I compare with @ciao's function, since it is the fastest of the earlier methods):

```
data = RandomInteger[10000, 10^6];
r1 = runningCount[data]; //RepeatedTiming
r2 = cnts[data]; //RepeatedTiming
r1 === r2
```

> {0.026, Null}
>
> {0.17, Null}
>
> True

Answer (score 4):

Use Table:

```
l = {4, 2, 4, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0};

counts[l_] := 
 Table[{l[[n]], Count[l[[1 ;; n]], l[[n]]]}, {n, Length[l]}]

counts[l]
```

{{4, 1}, {2, 1}, {4, 2}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}, {0, 2}, {0, 3}, {2, 
  2}, {0, 4}, {0, 5}}

Answer (score 0):

```
Catenate[KeyValueMap[Thread[{#, Range[Length[#2]]}] &,
  #]][[Ordering[Catenate[Values[#]]]]] &[PositionIndex[l]]
```

> {{4, 1}, {2, 1}, {4, 2}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}, {0, 2}, {0, 3}, {2, 2}, {0, 4}, {0, 5}}